# sorting a string of numbers that each have a letter inside. making sure to keep the same position of duplicates as in the original array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a string  of numbers. each number has a letter randomly placed inside of the number. I need to sort those numbers based on the letter inside of each number alphabetically. However if there are duplicates, I have to keep the order from the original string. for example: "c21 32b 43a 2c3" must be sorted to "43a 32b c21 2c3" then i need to strip the letters out.

here is what i have so far:

```js
function cats(s) {

  let arr = s.split(' ').sort(function (a,b) {
      return a.match(/[a-z]/i)[0].localeCompare(b.match(/[a-z]/i)[0]);
  });
console.log(arr)
   for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/\D/g,'');
  }

  console.log(arr)
}

cats('y381 6a684 9c94 5x346 c9541 31w1 440x16 x620 1b33 y4773 c3019');
```

I can't seem to get the duplicate letters to sort correctly. this is important because later on i need to perform math on these numbers and the order is important to get the correct solution.

Comment: how does the letter define the sorting?

Comment: @NinaScholz it goes alphabetically. let me update the post with that information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep an array of the split strings as a reference and use the index  to sort by when the letters match

```
let refArr = s.split(' ');

let arr = refArr.slice().sort(function (a,b) {
  let aLetter = a.match(/[a-z]/i)[0], bLetter=b.match(/[a-z]/i)[0];
  if(aLetter === bLetter){
     return refArr.indexOf(a) - refArr.indexOf(b);
  }else{
     return aLetter.localeCompare(bLetter);
  }     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just require a small mod, basically do a map before the sort, to store the array index, the sort then can use the index to do a composite sort, and then we use map to put back into the format you had before.

```js
function cats(s) {
  let arr = s.split(' ').
     map(function (v,i) { return {v:v, i:i }}).
     sort(function (a,b) {
       return a.v.match(/[a-z]/i)[0].localeCompare(b.v.match(/[a-z]/i)[0]) || a.i - b.i}).
     map(function (v) { return v.v; });        
  console.log(arr)
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/\D/g,'');
  }
  console.log(arr)
}

cats('y381 6a684 9c94 5x346 c9541 31w1 440x16 x620 1b33 y4773 c3019');
```

Comment: this is a really good answer. thank you! i picked one of the other ones because it was a bit simpler. but i am learning a lot from this one as well. so, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) and get a new array with the sorted items. This maintains the order of the items with same letters.

```js
var array = 'y381 6a684 9c94 5x346 c9541 31w1 440x16 x620 1b33 y4773 c3019'.split(' ');

var mapped = array.map((el, i) => ({ index: i, letter: el.match(/[a-z]/i)[0] }));

// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort((a, b) => a.letter.localeCompare(b.letter) || a.index - b.index);

// container for the resulting order
var result = mapped.map(el => array[el.index]);
   
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! i will have to look up map and learn more about it